# How to join the value of two variables in the output of the command to convert in json mode with Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, jsonpath

with powershell I can get, with just one line (prerequisite) and using foreach, the date of last update of the folders and the difference in days, however, I need to get this information in a format for use via json and I can't display the value of $pasta with the value of $DiasV why when converting with "| convertto-Json" the result is not in the correct format (I'm validating via https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser).

```
foreach ($pasta in Get-ChildItem -Path C:\TEMP\ -Directory) 
{
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';
$path = 'C:\TEMP\' + $pasta + '\EXAMPLE';
$start = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime -Last 1;
$end = Get-Date; $DiasV = (New-TimeSpan -Start $start -End $end);
write $pasta.Name $pasta.LastWriteTime $DiasV.Days | ConvertTo-Json 
}
```

Output:

```
[
    "A123_1A_CAB",
    {
        "value":  "\/Date(1649508388226)\/",
        "DateTime":  "sábado, 9 de abril de 2022 09:46:28"
    },
    0
]
[
    "C166_5AND_BBB",
    {
        "value":  "\/Date(1649610666329)\/",
        "DateTime":  "domingo, 10 de abril de 2022 14:11:06"
    },
    2
]
```

My intention is to get this output:

```
[
    {
        "pasta":  "A123_1A_CAB"
        "value":  "\/Date(1649508388226)\/",
        "DateTime":  "sábado, 9 de abril de 2022 09:46:28"
        "Dias":  "0"
    },
    {
        "pasta":  "C166_5AND_BBB"
        "value":  "\/Date(1649610666329)\/",
        "DateTime":  "domingo, 10 de abril de 2022 14:11:06"
        "Dias":  "2"
    }
]
```

I need help to solve this, already tried several ways without success.I'm still learning english.

Comment: *"with just one line (prerequisite)"* This sounds more like a vain challenge than a requirement. How is "just one line" supposed to be a prerequisite?

Comment: Trying to cram code in one line is asking for mistakes/errors that are hard to spot. Write multiline code, so it reads better

Comment: @Tomalak This prerequisite is why I'm going to use it in a monitoring with Zabbix using system.run and it can only be one line

Comment: @EdsonSFreitas Every PowerShell code can be rewritten to be on one line. Let's focus your question on getting working code, you can replace the newlines with semicolons on your own later.

Comment: I agree, but I really need to do it all in a single line to use a zabbix template without relying on scripts on the host but I welcome suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @EdsonSFreitas, did you find a problem with the answer that made you un-accept it? If so, let us know what it is, specifically, so it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is that you want the output to be converted to a *single* JSON array:

- By placing your [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) call *inside* your `foreach` loop, you're creating a *separate* JSON document in each iteration, which when *combined* as-is result in *malformed* JSON.
- Simply apply `ConvertTo-Json` to *all* your output objects, *across all loop iterations* instead; this is more easily accomplished if you switch to a single pipeline that uses the 
  [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet.
- Additionally, you need to encapsulate the pieces of information to report for each directory in an *object* whose *properties* contain the information:

To put it all together, with some optimizations:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\TEMP\ -Directory |
  ForEach-Object { 
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';
    $path = $_.FullName + '\EXAMPLE';
    $start = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -File | 
               Sort-Object -Property CreationTime |
                 Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime -Last 1;
    $end = Get-Date; $DiasV = ($end - $start).Days;
    # Create a helper object for the "value" and "DateTime" properties. 
    $dateTimeCustom = $_.LastWriteTime | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json
    # Output the pieces of information encapsulated in an object.
    [pscustomobject] @{ 
      pasta = $_.Name;
      value = $dateTimeCustom.value;
      DateTime = $dateTimeCustom.DateTime;
      Dias = $DiasV
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Note:

- The only reason I've kept the `;` at the end of the statements is to facilitate transforming the code into a *single line*. As written, the `;` are *not* necessary.
- Your output implies that you're using *Windows PowerShell*, where `ConvertTo-Json` serializes `[datetime]` values as *objects with two or three properties*, `.value` (a custom string representation based on the Unix epoch time representation, e.g., `"\/Date(1649508388226)\/"`), `.DateTime`, a friendly display string, and - if the `[datetime]` instance was obtained via `Get-Date` - additionally a `.DisplayHint` property.

  - To "flatten" these properties and make them direct properties of the output objects, a round-trip JSON conversion is used to create a helper object with those property values (`$dateTimeCustom = $_.LastWriteTime | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json`).

    - Strictly speaking, that `ConvertTo-Json` in Windows PowerShell produces an *object with properties* for a `[datetime]` instance - instead of just a *single string* such as `"\/Date(1649508388226)\/"` - should be considered a *bug*, not least because round-tripping such an object does *not* result in a `[datetime]` instance, but in a `[pscustomobject]` instance with properties `.value` and `.DateTime` and situationally also `.DisplayHint` (which we take advantage of here).
    - The problem occurs, because `[datetime]` instances are decorated with a type-level [ETS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) `ScriptProperty` member, `.DateTime`, which, unfortunately, is included in the serialization, resulting in the two-property object representation at hand. If you were to remove the type data associated with `[datetime]`, the problem would go away (but so would the property), e.g.:

      ```
      # Windows PowerShell only.
      # Note that if you were to use Get-Date output, *another*,
      # instance-level ETS property would come into play, .DisplayHint
      PS> Remove-TypeData System.DateTime; [datetime]::now | ConvertTo-Json
      "\/Date(1649702531387)\/"  # e.g. - single string
      ```
- Note that *PowerShell (Core) 7+* no longer uses this custom-object representation and instead serializes `[datetime]` instances as *strings* in ISO 8601 date-time format (e.g., `"2021-10-11T13:27:12.3318432-04:00"`)